# Use a custom dynamic linker with gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb, glibc

I have built a custom version of glibc. It introduces some new symbols that I use with a custom shared library. For this I add a new version: `SHIM`

I use `gcc -g -o my_test my_test.c -l my_so.so -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/local/home/me/glibc-build/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to build a test executable. It needs to use the runtime linker of my custom glibc build so it can link the custom glibc symbols used in my_so.so. This actually works.

But when I use `gdb` to debug the executable, I find that the default runtime linker is used. I get the following error:

> /bin/bash: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: version `SHIM' not found (required by /local/home/me/glibc-build/libc.so.6)

How can I have gdb use my custom runtime linker? I tried to use `gdb --args /local/home/me/glibc-build/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./my_test`, but I end up with the same error

Answer (score 0):

> I use `gcc -g -o my_test my_test.c -l my_so.so -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/local/home/me/glibc-build/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to build a test executable.

Using above command to link the executable is *incomplete*. I am guessing that you must also set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/local/home/me/glibc-build:/local/home/me/glibc-build/elf:...`  in order to make `my_test` work, and it that setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that is preventing `/bin/bash` from working.

You can confirm this by running (in your current environment):

```
bash -c ./my_test
```

which is exactly what GDB is doing, and which should fail with the same error.

If my guess is correct, the best way to fix this is to unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and relink your executable with `-Wl,-rpath=/local/home/me/glibc-build:/local/home/me/glibc-build/elf:...` so that `my_test` doesn't require setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all.